# Logstash not sending data to elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

```
input { 
   file{
path => "C:/elastic_stack/*.csv"
start_position => "beginning"
sincedb_path => "null"
     }
}
filter {
csv { separator => ","
columns => ["name","mfr","type","calories","protein","fat","sodium","fiber","carbo","sugars","potass","vitamins","shelf","weight","cups","rating"]
}
}
output {
elasticsearch
{ hosts => "http://localhost:9200/"
  index => "cereals"
}
stdout {}
}
```

in the cmd i see the message
[2021-03-28T20:27:02,468][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2021-03-28T20:27:02,531][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ][main][f09c0225c6dfc66bb50a8d3706ec14e066921c92842bc5680d0b5bb0aee01580] START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
[2021-03-28T20:27:02,554][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2021-03-28T20:27:02,985][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}

But the data is not getting send to elastic search. In kibana im not able to create an index.

Answer (score 0):

did it print anything to stdout? if not, then no line of the .csv file was parsed.

It seems you are on a windows machine, then try to disable sincedb_path by setting its value to `NUL` (https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-file/issues/26)